# How to show paidby and check_number on Contribution - Receipt (on-line)

Tags: civicontribute, smarty, templates

CiviCRM 5.16.3 on Drupal 7.
I would like to show payment menthods of contribution in template Contribution - Receipt (on-line). I tried to insert $formValues.paidby or $paidby but they show nothing.
(I saw those variables at off-line version of receipt and copied the them without even knowing if they are populated in the on-line workflow.)

How can I show payment methods and check numbers like those in off-line version?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out myself.

Put this API call somewhere upfront in the template. This retrieve contribution payment method by ID. (Get the whole record if removing "return" parameter.)

```
     {crmAPI var='apiResult' entity='Contribution' action='get' return="payment_instrument_id" contribution_id=$contributionID}
```

At where it should be displayed:

```
     {foreach from=$apiResult.values item=contribution}

         {$contribution.payment_instrument}

     {/foreach}
```