# Showing Payment Methods on Civi Receipt

Tags: paypal, receipts

We currently accept two payment methods: PayPal and Credit Card.
Is there a way to show which payment method was used in the transaction on the CiviContribute  receipt?

I'd like to show it in this table within my receipt:

{ts}Credit Card Information{/ts}
       
      
      
       
        {$credit_card_type}
        {$credit_card_number}
        {ts}Expires{/ts}: {$credit_card_exp_date|truncate:7:''|crmDate}

Thanks

Comment: try using `{$paidBy}` variable in the receipt template.

Comment: @jitendra-fuzion thanks. that didn't work :(

Comment: {$contribution.payment_instrument} might work - I played around with using it while testing but didn't implement it.  I found reference to it here, though I didn't need to include the api call at the top - https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/33149/how-to-show-paidby-and-check-number-on-contribution-receipt-on-line

Comment: Thanks @Christopher. I got it to show the Payment Type of "Credit Card" but I need to figure out how to show "Payment Processor Type" - since that'll show if it's PayPal or not. Any tips?